# How to put a newline in a template string

Tags: javascript

I have a template string where in I'm using an `array` like this:

```
var templateString = `array is ${arr.join(",\n")}`;
```

The newline doesn't show up. How can I put a newline in this case?

Comment: Works fine as is. Probably you're trying to display it as HTML, in which case you need to use HTML line breaks (`<br>`).

Comment: that code actually works.

Comment: Your code is just fine. if you want to break the string in html use `<br>` instead of `\n`

Comment: Tried your code in a console and it worked.

Comment: Where you are displaying string in `html` or `console`?

Comment: If html, you want to use <br />. If you're wanting to put this in a console or some file, use \n or \n\r (carriage return to represent the end of the input);

Comment: im using it in a tooltip. Im getting only the first element of the array and a comma.

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly if you're trying to display it in the console:

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var templateString = `array is ${arr.join(",\n")}`;
console.log(templateString);
```

If you want to display it in HTML, use a HTML linebreak (`<br>`):

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3];
var templateString = `array is ${arr.join(",<br />")}`;
document.write(templateString);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
var arr = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "dd"];
var templateString = `array is ${arr.join(",<br>")}`;
//This is getting displayed in HTML hence used break line so that it renders.
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = templateString;
```